# Padding has blue border in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

Okay, just to make it quick.

1) Go to www.simplefire.com.au 
   - with Firefox / IE
   - with Chrome.

2) The image on the right seems to have blue border on Firefox / IE, but Chrome displays the 
   page perfectly.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

I'm using wordpress and if it helps my style.css could be found here:
http://shortText.com/m5c9l0pel

Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `border: 0` to the style for the image.

Answer (score 0):

No worries guys, I found it out.
Change the "padding" to "margin" and it works fine. 
img style="margin:20px"